# Set selectedItems with selectedIndex telerik WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I'm trying to set the selected items in RadMultiColumnComboBox ( telerik control ) .

I know that selected item will return the object that is selected. Selected index returns the location in the list as an int.

For that reason I have used `Selectedindex` property and I got what I need if the `SelectionMode = "single"` using selectindex :

```
       md = new PersonController().GetPerson(mdl.id);
       int index = list.FindIndex(r => r.firstName.Equals(md.firstName));

       mycbx.SelectedIndex = index;
```

but what if I have multi selected items , how can I set the selectindex ??

**Update :**

```
           <telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox telerik:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior.SelectedItemsSource="{Binding selecteditems}"  x:Name="daysdepcbx" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="200" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="0,10,10,0" Height="80"
                                                               
                            FontStyle="Normal"
                            
                            DropDownWidth="530"
                            DropDownHeight="255" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office2013" SelectionMode="Multiple">
```

Comment: Index is for single selection, you need to either work with selecteditems property, or get a SelectionChanged event from the cell/column/inner control and handle the change.

Comment: The selecteditems work but only in the display , however, when I open the combobox of telerik , I didn't find anything selected in the datagrid of the multicolumncombobox

Comment: Did you set the column to handle multi selection? Show your xaml and code that handle the datagrid/column.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: According to documentation, in Multiple mode, you need to work with the SelectionChanged event of the control: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmulticolumncombobox/features/selection.
So no two way binding will work. You can write your own Behavior for this control, handle the event inside, and expose an observable collection dependency property called SelectedItems for purpose of binding.

Comment: I asked on the forum and I got an answer like this , but the problem is that I don't have any idea about ViewsModel and the the page contains the combobox was set to other design , I can't change it to another ViewModel https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-selecteditems-with-selectedindex-for-radmulticolumncombobox

Comment: Can you change the xaml of the page? If so, then like I said, write a Behavior that will handle the event, and do what you want, and apply it to the control.

Comment: No for now I can't change it

Comment: Can you change the code behind of that view?